# Reject records where associations have specific attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 3 models as:

```
class Server
  has_many: games
end

class Game
  belongs_to: server
  has_many: players
end

class Player
  belongs_to: game
end
```

The `Player` model has an attribute `valid` which may be true/false

Now I want to get a list of `games` which belong to a particular `server` but while pulling the `games` for a `server` I want to reject all `games` which **ONLY** have `players` with attribute `valid` set as `true`.

Any `game` which has even one `player` with attribute `valid` as `false` should show up in the result.

I can do it the following way:

```
@server.games.reject { |g| g.players.reject(&:valid).empty? }
```

But this seems highly inefficient. Is there a better way to implement the same?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to renamed you column `valid` to something else because it is already used by `ActiveRecord` & `ActiveModel::Errors` (see `valid?` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1** using a `INNER JOIN`:

```
games_with_invalid_players = Game.joins(:players).where(players: { valid: false })
# add .distinct at the end if you want to remove the duplicated game records
```

**Option 2** using a sub-select:

```
game_ids = Player.where(valid: false).select(:game_id).distinct
games_with_invalid_players = Game.where(id: game_ids)
```

Comment: I like the first one, it is neat and clean and it also makes only one query.